# Firebase auth.signOut() does not log out in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

This is my signOut code but it is not working. I tried many ways but I couldn't find a solution.

```
@IBAction func signOutButton(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toViewController", sender: nil)
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

when I clicked button, segue works but app doesnt log out

Comment: Welcome to SO. How do you know it's not working? You should also be catching errors and then outputting them see [logOut](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#next_steps) for some sample code. Please update the question with details so we can better understand the context.

Comment: @Jay when i run again my app, its showing my feed page its not going to sign in page

Comment: Does it print an error? If so, what's the error. If not, then the issue is the segue, not the signOut.